# How to check out remote tag without creating local tag

Tags: git

In git, if I want to checkout a branch from a remote without creating a local branch I can run:

`git checkout remotename/branchname`

and I will be left with a detached head pointing in the correct place.

How do I do exactly the same, to checkout a tag present on a remote **without creating a local tag**?

I can see that a tag exists on a remote like this:

```
git ls-remote --tags remotename
8189b9a4b6ba066c4f29544d1b755b5fd2426b62  refs/tags/v3.3
89a3f254b63819035f65d9c5dcdae8864f1a6a8a  refs/tags/v3.4
```

None of the following appear to work:

```
git checkout remotename/tagname
git checkout remotename/tags/tagname
git checkout remotename/refs/tags/tagname
```

I do not want to run `git fetch --tags` or anything equivalent because I do not want to create a local tag (maybe I already have a tag with the same name and I do not want to clobber it).

Short of copy+pasting the git hash, how do I checkout the tag by the name that I can see with `ls-remote --tags`?

(Also to complicate things further the remote has some branches with the same names as tags but pointing to different commits).

**Edit:**

I understand now that `remotename/branchname` is a local reference, which is created automatically by `git fetch` without arguments.

Is someone able to provide a command which will fetch all tags on a remote into local references of the form `remotename/tags/tagname`, rather than ordinary tags?

Thanks,

Comment: "Local" needs to be qualified. `remotename/branchname` *does* exist on your local machine, just not as a branch head. In that sense, it's quite similar to a tag, the difference being that it *does* refer to a branch head on the *remote* machine.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that except for a very small number of commands, `git` doesn't know anything about remote repositories and only operates on local data.

When you `git checkout remotename/branchname`, you're dealing only with *local* references: when you clone a repository or update the local cache of the remote with `git fetch/pull/remote update/etc`, git is creating *local* references for all the remote branches (prefixed by the remote name).

If you want to check out a "remote" tag, you need that reference available locally as well. You get that by running `git pull --tags`, or an equivalent command.

Now, you can of course extract the commit id from the output of `git ls-remote --tags`. Given your example output from that command:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags remotename
8189b9a4b6ba066c4f29544d1b755b5fd2426b62  refs/tags/v3.3
89a3f254b63819035f65d9c5dcdae8864f1a6a8a  refs/tags/v3.4
```

You can run `git checkout 8189b9a4b6ba066c4f29544d1b755b5fd2426b62` if you want to check out the commit referenced by `refs/tags/v3.3`.